# Attempt by security transparent method Umbraco 7

Tags: deployment, umbraco7

I have built an Umbraco 7 site locally using visual studio, and this is the first time i am deploying it to an hosting provider.

I have tested it on a local IIS

I have also checked with the hosting provider that the site has full-trust.

I have published the site using visual studio and uploaded it to the hosting via FTP.

Unfortunately i am still getting this error after deploying the site:

```
    Attempt by security transparent method 'Umbraco.Core.BindingRedirects.Initialize()' 
    to access security critical method

'System.AppDomain.add_AssemblyResolve(System.ResolveEventHandler)' failed.

Assembly 'Umbraco.Core, Version=1.0.6428.37121, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
is partially trusted,
  which causes the CLR to make it
 entirely security transparent regardless of any
transparency annotations in the assembly itself.
In order to access security critical code, this 
assembly must be fully trusted.
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a trust level issue on the hosting side. Is the website running in full trust? If not, your Umbraco 7 site won't work, as I believe it requires full trust these days.